# What is causing this nav animation and how do I stop it? (Divi Theme)

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm creating my site and I've tried searching for the CSS animation that is causing the text on the nav to appear on the left over the logo then to move to the right.

I'd like to simply keep the nav menu text there without any animation. Using DIVI theme.

http://nerdypreneur.com/

If you can help, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Radiaktive, its not an animation. Below is the css that I think you can use to solve this issue.

```
// Put this in your css or update it.

.et_header_style_left .logo_container {
    /* position: absolute; */ // Remove this from your css
    /* width: 100%; */ // Remove this from your css
    /* height: 100%; */ // Remove this from your css
    float: left;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.et_header_style_left .logo_container a {
    max-width: 120px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.et_fixed_nav #et-top-navigation {
    padding-left: 40px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.!

Answer (score 0):

It's not an animation. What happens is that the menu appears with a float: left; (this makes the menu appear aligned left over logo image) by a css selector #et-top-navigation from et-divi-customizer-global-XXXXXXX.min.css

Then some javascript/jquery when finishes to load, adds a style attribute with padding-left: 186px; to the menu so the menu moves right 186px.